# NSMutableArray - Query items without enumeration?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Using LINQ in .Net I can select items from an array that match a particular criteria i.e. from an array called People:

```
var cleverPeople = People.Where(o=>o.IQ>110);
```

Is there anything similar I can do to an NSMutableArray? I have many items in it and enumerating it with a loop is pretty costly performance wise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [`-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate:).

Comment: beautiful. exactly what I needed.

 NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isFired == NO"];
 NSArray *filtered = [self.arenamap filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];

Comment: Here's a nice write-up on NSPredicate vs LINQ.
http://www.cimgf.com/2008/08/24/cocoa-tutorial-c-linq-or-cocoa-key-paths-and-nspredicate/

Comment: Note that this will probably not be much faster than iterating the loop yourself. Fundamentally to select items from an array like this, the whole array must be iterated over somewhere along the line

Answer (score 4):

I have created a simple library, called [Linq to ObjectiveC](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC), which is a collection of methods that provide a Linq-style query interface. In your case you need the [Linq-to-ObjectiveC where](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/LinqToObjectiveC#where) method:

```
NSArray* peopleWhoAreSmart = [people where:^BOOL(id person) {
    return [[person iq] intValue] > 110;
}];
```

This returns an array of of people where their IQ > 110.

Comment: Nice — good tip. The lack of these obvious methods in Cocoa's collection classes is mind-boggling. (Also, funnily enough, this wouldn't have been possible when the question was originally posted, as blocks weren't around yet. Yay progress.)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [Higher Order Messaging](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HigherOrderMessaging) to implement select.  For example,

```
NSArray* cleverPeople = [[People select] greaterIQ:110];
```

Where greaterIQ would be a category method on People.

Answer (score 0):

Of course these (10.6+) days we've got nice APIs like `indexOfObjectPassingTest` to do things like

```
var smartPeople = [People indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id person, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
                  {  return person.iq > 110; } ];
```